# Optimising by Group of own function in r

Tags: r, optimization, plyr

I would like to apply an optimization by group on my own function:

Here a reproducable data set:

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3),C=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4),
                   Lambda=c(0.5),s=c(1:7),   
                   sigma_S=c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.5,0.8),
                   d=c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80), 
                   sigma_B=0.3,t=5,Rec=0.5,r=0.05)
```

My function is defined as follows (the function is trivial, i just want to understand the method):

```
  TestMSE <- function(LR)
  {
    d <- data
    D <- LR + d$s
    mse(d$C, D)   # mse is from the Metrics Package
   }

optimize(TestMSE,lower = 0.1, upper =1.5)
```

I tried using the ddply function:

```
test <-  ddply(data,"ID",summarise, optimize(TestMSE,lower = 0.1, upper =1.5))
```

But applying the ddply function I receive the same solution for all of my groups, although there is a difference by subgroups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, as @Joran pointed out is that your function `TestMSE` had no way of obtaining the split data from `ddply`. So, you should have an argument for the input data that provides the data for each group. Try something like this, maybe?

```
TestMSE <- function(LR, d) {
    D <- LR + d$s
    mse(d$C, D)
}

require(plyr)
require(Metrics)
test <-  ddply(data,"ID", function(x) {
    unlist(optimize(TestMSE, 0.7, x, lower = 0.1, upper =1.5))
})

#   ID   minimum objective
# 1  1 0.1000519  1.876781
# 2  2 0.1000519  7.010270
# 3  3 0.1000519  9.610322
```

aha, now I understand what you require. It can be done with `merge`:

```
merge(data, test, by="ID")

#   ID C Lambda s sigma_S  d sigma_B t Rec    r   minimum objective
# 1  1 1    0.5 1     0.5 20     0.3 5 0.5 0.05 0.1000519  1.876781
# 2  1 1    0.5 2     0.4 30     0.3 5 0.5 0.05 0.1000519  1.876781
# 3  1 1    0.5 3     0.3 40     0.3 5 0.5 0.05 0.1000519  1.876781
# 4  2 2    0.5 4     0.7 50     0.3 5 0.5 0.05 0.1000519  7.010270
# 5  2 2    0.5 5     0.4 60     0.3 5 0.5 0.05 0.1000519  7.010270
# 6  3 3    0.5 6     0.5 70     0.3 5 0.5 0.05 0.1000519  9.610322
# 7  3 4    0.5 7     0.8 80     0.3 5 0.5 0.05 0.1000519  9.610322
```

Comment: Thanks, that works just great! Could you also explain me how to create an extra column with the minimum according the ID?

Comment: Maybe I don't follow what you require but I think the answer I've shown gives ID and the minimum along with the objective...

Comment: Yes, indeed. Additionally I would like to add a column in `d` with the value of the minimum of each  `ID`. Since the length of `test` is shorter compared to `d`, I don't know how to add the column using the `transform`option in `ddply`